# What is Universal Google Analytic custom dimension character/byte limit

Tags: cross-browser, google-analytics

I know that **General GA** data is sent by 1 pixel **.gif** request data. Where custom value **[key, value]** pair combined length had maximum fixed size. One limiting factor was IE older browsers that had maximum byte (not sure, but I assumed it was 2048 byte's for all values).

I assumed also that it was encoded in UTF-8 (variable-length multibyte encoding) where character can take 1-4 bytes in length. At some point in time I read that maximum character limit for custom value is 150 characters. At the time I did not need to know any better.

In case **Universal GA** the **key** part is stored in GA server and never sent. If I am not mistaken, each custom value has a separate request.

```
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x', 'xxx');
ga('set', {
    'dimension1': '...',
    'dimension2': '...',
    'dimension3': '...',
    'dimension4': '...',
    'dimension5': '...'
});
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

My question is how meany bytes/characters **`'...'`** can have in case of Universal GA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encoded custom dimension value may not exceed 150 Bytes.

- Best case: **150** characters
- Worst case : **37** characters

> > Reference: [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#customs)

Comment: It is not characters, it is bytes, so in case Unicode characters are used, it will be less. Can you please explain how did you calculate the worst case limit?

Comment: I guess that the worst case is where all characters are 4 bytes long (the maximum in utf-8). 150/4 = 37,5. See also https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference#maxlength